# Twitter API for posting video or pic

Tags: php, javascript, html

Please help me to upload a file (pic or video) along with tweet on twitter from my website.I was trying but only able to get code for tweeting so anyone here please help me to do this task

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you don't upload pictures and videos to Twitter. You put them as a link in to the actual tweet, and the content is expected to be hosted outside twitter.

Comment: And is the OP really not Khan, but instead Mark Zuckerberg!

Comment: Thnx Red I came to know this by using twitpic.com

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Twitter API's `statues/update_With_media` [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media) to upload an image (it uses photo bucket on their back-end).

You can also go to the libraries page and download a php library, I think the one in bold is the only one which currently supports file upload (although I'm slowly working on one). One issue you might run into is your tweet CAN NOT start with an @ tag else php will treat it as a file upload, although you can pad a space on there and twitter will trim it (for now).